# Correct way to write or even better combine these two Excel 2007 formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have two formulas. As an example for this question let's assume I have a workbook that is basically a CD Database. It contains all the usual information that you would expect.
This workbook is called `Album.xls`.

I also have another workbook called `Data.xls` that contains a number of worksheets; each worksheet pulls different data from `Album.xls`.

As you know, different music CDs have a varying number of discs per album – some can only have one disc, some two, others three and so on.

In `Album.xls`, all of the information for each separate CD is contained across the rows (one CD per row).
The Number Of Disc information is in Column F. The data is always a number, so disc 1 (within an album/title) is represented by the number 1, disc 2 by the number 2, and so on up to a max of 8 discs.

I have a worksheet in `Data.xls` in which I am trying to pull the disc count per title; e.g., how many discs does a particular album have.

I am using the two formulas below to do this but I am sure I am going about it in an unnecessarily long-winded or maybe even incorrect way, so I wonder if any one can suggest a better way.

In my Disc count worksheet of `Data.xls`...

In each cell of Column A, I have

```
=IF(OR([Album.xls]Track!$F$2=1), "Disc 1", IF(OR([Album.xls]Track!$F$2=2), "Disc 2", ""))
```

For each cell downwards the cell reference in the formula advances by 1 so in `A1` the cell reference is `$F$2`, in `A2` it's `$F$3`, and so on...

The idea is this formula looks at the F Column of `Album.xls` and, for each cell in Column F, if it finds a number 1 it displays `Disc 1`; if it finds a number 2 it displays `Disc 2`; and so on...

In each cell of Column B I have

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$400, MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($B$1:B4,$A$2:$A$20),0,0),0))
```

This looks at the results of the first formula in Column A and returns only unique values, so, if a CD album has 3 discs, it would result in the top three cells displaying:

```
Disc 1  
Disc 2  
Disc 3
```

If it had 5 discs it would display:

```
Disc 1  
Disc 2
Disc 3
Disc 4
Disc 5
```

And so on...

Sorry if this is long-winded; I am sure my newbie is showing through
and I am doing this the hard way so I am hoping to learn from you.

Comment: You have a somewhat complicated system, and it can be hard for someone else to understand it by working backwards through the formulas you've used (which, as you say, might not be the most efficient solution).  It will be much easier for people to help if you can add a couple of things to your question.  1) add a mockup or screenshots of some sample data (a picture is worth 1,000 words). 2) Using that image as a basis, explain what you want to accomplish (the result, using a mockup), and the applicable logic to arrive there.  That will also clarify what goes in single vs. multiple cells.

Comment: If all you want it the count, rather than specifically to display "Disc 1 Disc 2" etc, you can get this much more simply. I assume you have some unique identifier for each album which is present on both sheets. Simply use COUNTIF to see how many instances of this exist on the CATraxx_Album worksheet. If it needs to be a compound key (e.g. artist + title) to be unique, you can use COUNTIFS similarly.

Comment: Why not use a pivot table?

Comment: I edited your question a little.  I believe that it still needs more work, although, if you have the answer that you want, I guess there’s not much point in putting much more effort into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For column A, you can use:

```
="Disc "&[CATraxx_Album.xls]Track!$F2
```

this will give output of "Disc X", where X is the value in [CATraxx_Album.xls]Track!$F2.

The ampersand (&) operator concatenates strings in excel formula, so `="A"&"B"` would output AB.  It's a very useful operator as you can use it to concatenate many things, e.g `="hello "&C1&", nice to meet you! My name is "&C2&"."` (where C1 and C2 would contain names).

Note I have also removed the dollar sign between F and 2 in the formula for column A. This means that when you drag this formula down, the F number will increment, which I believe is what you want (you mention A1 should reference F2, A2 reference F3, etc).

Although you have stated what column B does, you haven't said what is wrong with it or how you want to change the output.  If you let me know what you want to be different about that output, I can enhance my answer to address that as well.

Comment: @Kenny: You should see a checkmark to the left of the answer under the votes.  Just click on that.

Comment: Whoever gave me -1, please could you explain why??  It's not very helpful to downgrade without telling someone what they did wrong!

Comment: @namford, Hello and welcome on Stack Overflow! There's nothing wrong with your answer, don't worry! Perhaps someone didn't like the way you formatted it. You may want to click on the "edit" link and see what Twisty did to your answer to make it look better. If you do the same next time, your answers will look good from the start. And here's my upvote.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev - thank you!  Its tough when you are new on here and can't communicate because you have no rep, so I really appreciate the help :-) Hope I won't get into trouble for using the coments to say thanks :-/